# Servlet.init exception

Tags: java, jsp, maven, spring-mvc

Am developing MVC Spring Application have Maven nature. Everything seems OK, but recently I got this error :

```
Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
```

It is too strange. And I cannot understand what is the problem exactly !

```
exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

root cause 

org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.nortal.vspa.controller.HelloWorldController] for bean with name '/welcome.htm' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nortal.vspa.controller.HelloWorldController
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1250)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1319)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:885)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

dispather-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="/welcome.htm" class="com.nortal.vspa.controller.HelloWorldController" ></bean>
<bean name="/rate.htm" class="com.nortal.vspa.controller.RateController" ></bean>
```

vspa-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.nortal.vspa.controller" />
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: can you post full trace, there should be a root cause for this. Seems like init method of one of your servlets is throwing an exception

Comment: In fact, I would say that a servlet called "dispatcher" is the one that is causing the problem ...

Comment: @SubinS The trace stack posted now !

Comment: ClassNotFoundException: com.nortal.vspa.controller.HelloWorldController

Comment: make sure you have this dependency in classpath

Comment: at compile time it exists, but jvm is unable to find that class during runtime. Make sure that class is present in WEB-INF/classes if you are running tomcat

Comment: how are you starting the servlet container/server?

Comment: @SubinS The server is embedded on eclipse ! Tomcat 6.0

Comment: comment out <bean name="/welcome.htm" class="com.nortal.vspa.controller.HelloWorldController" ></bean>
 part and see if there is any error. Also try a cleanup on server, (right click and there will be option)

Comment: @SubinS i do cleaning using maven and working :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems reasonably clear:

```
Cannot find class [com.nortal.vspa.controller.HelloWorldController]
```

So you need to work out where that class is defined, and make sure it's in the appropriate classpath for that servlet, in a way that Spring is able to find it.

Comment: The class is defined sure 100% ! :(

Comment: @HatemSalem: I dare say it is, but clearly Spring can't find it. So you need to work out *why* Spring can't find it. We can't really help you with that without knowing more about how you've configured everything.

Comment: I will post the configuration and xml files.

Comment: @HatemSalem: That doesn't tell us anything about where your spring jar files are, or where your class files (or jar files) for `HelloWorldController` are.